# Invalid font filename (imagettfbox)

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

This question has been asked over and over but I could not find the correct answer to my problem... As a little background note, all the code was working perfectly before we moved the class file from /application/lib/class to /library/class ...

I have tried to play with GDFONTPATH, relative, absolute paths with and without the file extension to no avail. Here is some of the lines we have tried so far:

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'fonts'));
/*1*/  $FontName = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'fonts'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename($FontName,'.ttf');
/*2*/  $FontName = '\pChart\fonts\\'.basename($FontName);
/*3*/  $FontName =basename($FontName);
$coords = imagettfbbox($FontSize, 0, $FontName, $Text);
```

Multiple combination of those tries have also been used to no avail. I am really annoyed by this problem as the #1, when echo'ed gives a full path that opens up the correct font file if copy/pasted in win explorer.

It might help to know the absolute path of the file getting the error and the path of the fontname...

```
C:\wamp\www\application_bundle\Library\pChart\class\pImage.class.php
C:\wamp\www\application_bundle\Library\pChart\fonts\arialuni.ttf
```

We are experiencing this problem on all dev platforms (Win, Mac and Linux) PHP 5.3.13

Thank you for your assistance.

Edit: It seems as if the file is not found / the server is not looking at the right folder... If someone could help troubleshoot the problem by pointing out how to figure out what path GD is trying to open would really help.

Comment: You've tried forward slashes, right?  PHP on Windows understands both, but something deep in GD might not.

Comment: I hadn't thought it would make a difference... I tried without positive result.

Comment: Today, we have tried to use another font, refresh the library files and still no change.

Comment: @Salketer Have you checked if font has correct permissions i.e. gd is allowed to read it?

Comment: @PLB thank you for your thought, but yes we did think of that.

Comment: @Salketer It's really hard (I am afraid even impossible) to solve this problem so because we can't reproduce error but I can say what I'd do in this situation. If I were you, I'd sit down and write down every little detail (even if you think it's not related to issue) that has changed since working version and then analyze step-by-step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have figured out how to make it work.

To put it short, we were including the class file and then calling the methods to write the text. We were doing something like this:

```
$classPath = 'pChart/';
include($classPath.'/class/pImage.class.php');
//... inside the pImage.class we passed font like this: $FontName = $classPath.'/fonts/arialuni.ttf';
imagettfbbox($FontSize, 0, $FontName, $Text)
```

It did not work whatever we did before or after... Until we changed the $classPath to

```
$classpath = '../library/pChart/';
```

Note that they are (or should) point exactly to the same folder as the code is executed from a file in library root.

We have tried to find why absolute paths were not working but could not reproduce the bug in an isolated environment so there's something fishy with our architecture.

Thank you for your time everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered and accepted but I didn't see anyone chiming in on why this solution worked and what was incorrect in the first place.

**The short description of the problem**

The current working directory is established at the point php get's it's hands on the request and all relative paths are resolved based on the current working directory, not the directory of the file that the path is referenced in.

**The long description of the problem**

Relative paths in php are resolved based on the current working directory.

For testing purposes you can always see what the current working directory is by calling [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

This value is initially arrived at on an http request as the directory that contains the file that the web server initially handed off the request to php.

So for example if you go to http://www.mydomain.com/index.php the current working directory will be the same as the document root (`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`)

For a CLI request the cwd is the directory you are in when you execute the command. So if I am at `/home/orangepill`  and I run `/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php` the cwd will be `/home/orangepill`.

This causes a problem for relative file references within included files.

Lets take this example.

1. Client navigates to www.mydomain.com
2. Apache has index.php set in the DirectoryIndex directive and apache finds an index.php file in the document root. Current working directory is set to the document root.
3. /index.php contains the line  `include "library/myclass.php";`
   $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/library/myclass.php" exists and all is good
4. myclass.php contains the line `include("myclass_helper.php");` this resolves to $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myclass_helper.php". (*remember relative references resolve relative to the current working directory*)
5. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myclass_helper.php"` doesn't exist its actually in `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/library/myclass_helper.php"`

You are probably thing but wait... I've experienced different behavior in my scripts when including within an include. The reason for that is the include and require language constructs (along with a couple of other file system commands) try to include relative paths from each of the paths specified in the include path php directive. So in the above example if library directory off of the document root existed within the include paths then everything would work as expected.

A wholesale solution for requiring files relative to the current file is to structure your include paths using the `__DIR__` contextual constant.  So you would use `include __DIR__."/myclass_helper.php";` (`include dirname(__FILE__)."/myclass_helper.php` in pre PHP 5.3 environments) and at runtime this would effectively convert your relative path to an absolute path based on the location of the file doing the include.

For common include directories I have gotten into the habit of specifying a few commonly used locations for use with relative file system references. for example

```
define ("APPLICATION_PATH", realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/application");
define ("LIBRARY_PATH", realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/library");
define ("CONFIG_PATH", APPLICATION_PATH."/etc/";
```

This gives you a lot of anchor points to include paths relative to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It deserves some attention. But here the problem should not be the same as described... Including a file relatively to an include path works. The pChart file was correctly included using just 'pChart/' since it is in library, but the font would only be found if we included the file using '../library/pChart'. Unless I am still missing something, this made no sense to us.

Comment: This would indicate that the current working path was a directory that shared a parent with the library directory. Where is the path of the php file that first handled the apache request.

Comment: the index.php that received the request would need this path to be reached from library's parent: ./app1/www/

Answer (score 0):

Have you dumped `$FontName` before this piece of code to debug its value?

Anyway, if you're already setting `GDFONTPATH`, you don't need to use any path on `$FontName`, in this case you could just use the font name (*arialuni.ttf* or even just *arialuni*) or at most `basename()` function as in your #3 example.

Your `putenv()` call could be just `putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('../fonts'))`.

Try that to see if it works:

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('../fonts'));
$FontName = 'arialuni.ttf'; // note that I'm using font name directly
$coords = imagettfbbox($FontSize, 0, $FontName, $Text);
```

**Update 1**

Please, dump your `GDFONTPATH` and tell me what it prints. Add that after your `putenv()` call, it will force your code to raise an error with the `GDFONTPATH` it looked for:

```
 trigger_error(sprint('GDFONTHPATH = %s', getenv('GDFONTPATH')), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunatly this did not help :(

Comment: Please, read my answer update, let me try to figure out what's happening. :)

Answer (score 0):

One may also just try to state a link relative to the root directory. I had the same problem ("Invalid file font name", function "...") and fixed it like that in the main file where the pChart is being initialized:

```
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/lib/pChart/fonts/verdana.ttf"));
```

Solved the issue for me.
This line USED to be like that:

```
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"fonts/verdana.ttf"));
```

which - I don't know why - provoked an error today.

---

Please note that this solution is not very elegant since it relies on the fact that your pChart folder is actually located at something like

```
http://myHomepage.com/files/lib
```

, meaning it does not work with relative directories.