# unlink does not work on variable but works on exact path

Tags: php, variables, post, unlink

Absolute path works with unlink():

```
<?php
     unlink('images/filename.jpg');
?>
```

But this does not work.

```
<?php
    $image_id = $_POST['image_id'];
    unlink('images/'.$image_id)
?>
```

File permission is ok, script can read, write and execute. Tried with single and double quotes it works with absolute file path but not with variables passed from $_POST[].

Any workaround here? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right value in `$_POST['image_id']`? Do a `print_r()` and see.

Comment: Thanks! but nothing is printed.

Comment: I believe Rainulf meant `print_r($image_id)` after `$image_id = $_POST['image_id']`.  Is this what you did?

Comment: yes it prints the file name with its extension.

Comment: It should work then, unless the file is already deleted. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: see my answer here for what's probably going on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489573/invalid-font-filename-imagettfbox/17627419#17627419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be clean up your query parameters a little bit. Not sure of it, but as I tried out my codes with multiple variations, it worked just perfect !

According to you,

```
unlink('images/filename.jpg');
```

is working perfectly. Then, I see no reason why the other code is not working.

do something like:
    $image_id = trim($_POST["image_id"]);

and before deleting the file, please check, whether the file exists or not, that way, you will be sure where the error lies in.

```
$image_url = "images/{$image_id}";
if(file_exists($image_url)){
    unlink($image_url);
} else {
    die('file does not exist');
}
```

Comment: seems like some white spaces gave you all the troubles.

Comment: I am trying to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thanks to Rainulf, vinodadhikary, and especially to CooSHal.

Comment: No worries. It helped you, that's enough :D

Comment: Had this same issue and trim was what I needed - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    $image_id = $_POST['image_id'];
    unlink('./images/'.$image_id)
?>
```

Adding the "./" before the images in the directory name.

Comment: That's the same without `./`; it's both current directory.

Comment: By the way, the website is hosted on a linux server.